# Understanding overloading an operator, which is a struct

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I got the following code from code review which has been confusing me for a while.

```
class Window {
public:
    Window(int x, int y, int w, int h, bool fullScreen = false) {
        pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("", x, y, w, h, fullScreen);
        if (pWindow == nullptr)
            throw std::runtime_error("Unable to create window");
    }

    ~Window() { SDL_DestroyWindow(pWindow); }

    operator SDL_Window*() { return pWindow; }

private:
    SDL_Window *pWindow;
};
```

I am interested in line `operator SDL_Window*() { return pWindow; }`. The result of this line is that any instance of this class actually refers to the `pWindow` variable (a struct) that holds the actual SDL window (I have tested an verified this). But how. How does overloading  `SDL_Window*` operator cause the instance of that class to return `pWindow`, when it makes more sense to overload the actual `Window` class (if that even is a  thing).

I don' even understand what it means to overload `SDL_Window*` in this context.

Comment: Lookup cast operator.

Comment: It's an operator that allows cast conversion from type `Window` to type `SDL_Window*`

Comment: Specifically, see the answer on [conversion operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/16615725#16615725).